# CRM 2011 - Catch events of subgrid when a new record is inserted or an existing record is modified

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a **subgrid** in the CRM 2011 form.

While ***adding*** a new record to the subgrid, I want to catch the new record event, or while ***changing data*** inside any record, I want to catch it by event.

I see that it is possible to catch the refresh event - but it occurs only if somebody is clicking on the refresh button or by deleting a record.

Why its event is not fired when adding a new record or when modifying an existing record?

I see that the subgrid has events as follows: oninsertnewrecord, onrowupdated, but those events are not fired or cannot be overridden...

Answer (score 0):

While adding a new record you can clone the Add new standard and call your own logic before call the native add.
While changing data you can bind a function to the subgrid onrefresh but this is not supported.